# InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error: in inference part (building a transformer for timeseries using tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, transformer-model

In the inference part, when i want to predict the sequence of values using a transformer model within for loop, I get this

> InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error

and I couldn't resolve it.

The main thing that I couldn't understand is that the shape for first value is (none,1,1) [batch size, time steps, features)] for first iteration, but for the second iteration, instead of (none,2,1) I had (none, none,1)

This is my decoder code:

```
 class Decoder(Model):
  def __init__(self, sequence_length,  key_querry_dim, val_dim,  d_model, num_heads, d_ff, rate, n ,name = "Decoder", **kwargs):
    super( Decoder ,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.input_decoder = Input_FeedForward(d_model)
    self.pos_encoding =  PositionalEncoder(sequence_length, d_model)
    self.dropout = Dropout(rate)
    self.decoder_layer = [DecoderLayer( key_querry_dim, val_dim,  d_model, num_heads, d_ff, rate ) for _ in range(n)]

  def call(self, shifted_output_target, encoder_output, training,inference = False):

    x = self.input_decoder(shifted_output_target)
    # Generate the positional encoding
    if inference == True :
      print("decoder output " ,shifted_output_target.shape)
      print("decoder output after  projection ", x.shape)
      print("original pos encoding shape ",self.pos_encoding.shape)
      print("after slicing pos enc ", (self.pos_encoding[  :shifted_output_target.shape[1] , : ]).shape)


      pos_encoding_output = x + self.pos_encoding[  :shifted_output_target.shape[1] , : ]
      print("pos_encoding_output shape ", pos_encoding_output.shape)
    else :
      pos_encoding_output = x + self.pos_encoding
    

    # Add in a dropout layer
    x = self.dropout(pos_encoding_output, training=training)

    # Pass on the positional encoded values to each encoder layer
    for i, layer in enumerate(self.decoder_layer):
        x = layer(x, encoder_output,  training)

    return x

# decoder input

decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None, n_out_features ), name='decoder_inputs')
```

After building the model for train, this is model for inference:

```
input2 = Input(shape=(inp_win,d_model)) #encoder output that will be the decoder second input
decoder_output = decoder( decoder_inputs, input2 , training = False,inference = True)
model_output = model_last_layer(decoder_output)
decoder_model= Model([decoder_inputs , input2 ],model_output)
```

This is the inference code:

```
def run_transformer_inference( input_sequence): # input_sequence must have 3 dimensions [batch size, time_steps, n_in_feature]

  #get encoder output
  encoder_output = encoder_model.predict(input_sequence)


  #take last time step value of the input sequence, to be decoder input in first iteration of the loop below
  decoder_input=input_sequence[:,-1,:]  # shape = [batch size, n_out_feature]
  decoder_input = np.expand_dims(decoder_input ,axis=1)  # shape = [batch size,1, n_out_feature]

  print("first at all decoder input shape ", decoder_input.shape)
  print("encoder ", encoder_output.shape)

  for _ in range(out_win):
    print("iteration ", _)

    # Make prediction
    prediction = decoder_model.predict([decoder_input ,  encoder_output ])


    # Obtain the predicted value at step t+1 (last predicted value )
    last_predicted_value = prediction[:, -1, :] # shape = [batch size, n_out_feature]

    last_predicted_value =np.expand_dims(last_predicted_value,axis=1)  # shape = [batch size,1, n_out_feature]
    #print("last_predicted_value ",last_predicted_value.shape)


    decoder_input  = np.append(decoder_input,last_predicted_value ,axis = 1)

    #decoder_input = last_predicted_value
    print("decoder input shape ",decoder_input.shape)

  return out_seq
```

This is my output:

```
1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/step
```

First at all decoder input shape  (5, 1, 1)

```
Encoder  (5, 512, 512)

iteration  0

decoder output  (None, 1, 1)

decoder output after  projection  (None, 1, 512)

original pos encoding shape  (256, 512)

after slicing pos enc  (1, 512)

pos_encoding_output shape  (None, 1, 512)

1/1 [==============================] - 1s 1s/step

decoder input shape  (5, 2, 1)

iteration  1

decoder output  (None, None, 1)

decoder output after  projection  (None, None, 512)

original pos encoding shape  (256, 512)

after slicing pos enc  (256, 512)

pos_encoding_output shape  (None, 256, 512)

InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-b09d6f11c143> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 pred1_10=run_transformer_inference(x_test[:5])

---> 52     tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     53                                         inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     54   except core._NotOkStatusException as e:

InvalidArgumentError: Graph execution error:

    pos_encoding_output = x + self.pos_encoding[  :shifted_output_target.shape[1] , : ]
Node: 'model_1/decoder/add'
required broadcastable shapes
     [[{{node model_1/decoder/add}}]] [Op:__inference_predict_function_32631]
```

every iteration, the number of steps add one value untill i predict the whole sentence, thats why in the input shape of decoder i choose it to be none for the timesteps as you can see in the code below

as you can see in the message output for first iteration
iteration  0
decoder output  (None, 1, 1)
after slicing pos enc  (1, 512)
xhile in next iteration
iteration  1
decoder output  (None, None, 1) ( i need it to be (None, 2, 1) )
after slicing pos enc  (256, 512)  ( i need it to be ( 2, 512) )